How to handle a situation of performance of "peer" role with unclarity of what feedback they got so far?
I am a manager and some time back my manager asked for a developer of my team to be assigned to a new big initiative that is in a very early phase. So my developer moved there to work with a product manager (PM) and I had no involvement with the project at all.
Recently as the area started to get more resources I was asked to manage that team as well.
When I joined there was already a project planned with specific deadlines and in progress.
As I started looking into the details I realized that the whole topic is a mess. First of all all deliverables till now were delayed and there were multiple excuses for it. And the new project with tight deadlines is also running behind and it is quite hard to restore it back to track.
The reason for all of this is the PM. She has done a very poor job at gathering the right input, forming the requirements and has enforced the developers a direction to the project based on her own personal opinions and (mis)understandings on a multitude of topics.
Note that my manager initially had mentioned (not sure why) that she has a history of failed projects and I can see why.
I asked my manager what is the feedback for the progress of the whole area so far as I also explained the situation as I encountered it. My manager from on side did mention that it is indeed the case that there is much delay at deliveries but essentially tried to brush off any responsibility and also did not want to openly directly mention that there is indeed a problem.
What he suggested is we have a meeting with my PM and her manager and we can discuss about the project and the various problems.
Now I am very confused on how to navigate the situation. From one side, my intention is to bring the project back on track and help my PM to the degree she is open for my help. But I am unclear if the PM actually has any awareness of the situation.
Additionally I can't think of how the conversation that my manager proposed will be productive and won't escalate into some sort of conflict if the conversation would be about actually talking specifics on why the project has been delayed which are attributed to my PMs work.
How do you suggest I handle the situation and what do you think of the idea of the meeting?

Why do you want to manage a project with a PM that is failing? My suggestion is to retract your request to manage the team.

To second the comment by Donald - I feel there is some context missing here. Is this a flagship project or a project that has tangential benefits or impacts on you or your team?

@Donald: I was asked by my manager to manage the team that run this project. I  never asked to be involved.

@TheDemonLord: see earlier comment. The project falls under my manager who asked me to manage the team

@Jim, if you have been asked by the manager who is over the whole project to manage it, it would be best to go back to that manager and get full hire/fire authority so that you can bring the project under proper management.

@DavidR: So are you suggesting to not do the meeting my manager proposes and directly ask him to provide accountabilities explicitly?

@Jim What I suggest is that you be given the authority to fire that PM and bring in someone who can do the job. When the PM has a history of not being able to do the job, it is time to bring in someone who can.


From one side, my intention is to bring the project back on track and help my PM to the degree she is open for my help.

You're tasked with managing the developers, not the project. You should stick to your role, or, if you see it as being problematic, decline the role. Any involvement in the project management side of things makes you a potential scapegoat if/when it all falls to pieces.

This is helpful. The issue is that now, I am also responsible for the team's success along with the PM. So I am not sure to what extend I can just allow failure i.e. team does not deliver on promises when I can see it coming up by focusing only a small subset i.e. work with the developers only.

If you're not responsible for the project then it doesn't matter. If they want you to be responsible you need to make it clear that you need the sole authority to make things happen.
